# Jquery animation not working correctly, acting weird

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am new in jquery. I have just created a basic animation using .animate property. But the animation is acting weird. It is an hover animation. If i hover in a section it get smaller and animate. But If i hover the circle from the top it is working. If i hover from the bottom section it is not working.

Here is the code i have used

HTML:

```
 <div class="round_icon">
               <div class="round_content"> <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>
                 <p>GIFT</p></div>


  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.round_icon
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 30% auto 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    color: #fff;
}
.round_icon p
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: block
}
.round_icon i
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: block
}
.round_content
{
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 35px;
    left: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    width: 50%;
}
.round_icon2
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 5px solid #2A939C;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 30% auto 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    color: #2A939C !important
}
```

Jquery:

```
var main = function(){
    $('.round_icon').mouseover( function(){

        var style1 = {width:'200px', height: '200px'}
        $(this).animate(style1,200).addClass('round_icon2');

        });

$('.round_icon').mouseout( function(){

        var style2 = { width:'300px', height: '300px'}

        $(this).animate(style2,200).removeClass('round_icon2');

        }); 

    };


$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/a5Ljuqdn/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the mouse causing events on the inner circle (as you are processing mouse events on its parent and the child is stealing the mouse causing mouse out events on the parent).

Style the inner circle with `pointer-events: none;` to stop any interaction.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a5Ljuqdn/3/

```
.round_content {
  pointer-events: none;
```

You also need to stop existing animations to avoid bounces using `stop()`:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a5Ljuqdn/5/

```
var main = function () {
    $('.round_icon').mouseover(function () {
        var style1 = {
            width: '200px',
            height: '200px'
        }
        $(this).stop().animate(style1, 200).addClass('round_icon2');
    });

    $('.round_icon').mouseout(function () {
        var style2 = {
            width: '300px',
            height: '300px'
        }

        $(this).stop().animate(style2, 200).removeClass('round_icon2');
    });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Update. As there will always be a bounce issue on mouse hover when you are resizing the element being hovered, you need to shield it from extra mouse events. This example uses a busy flag to stop mouseover events until a mouse leave is received:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a5Ljuqdn/8/

```
var main = function () {
    // Stop additional mouse over when already processing a mouseout
    var busy = false;
    $('.round_icon').mouseover(function () {
        if (!busy) {
            var style1 = {
                width: '200px',
                height: '200px'
            }
            $(this).stop().animate(style1, 200).addClass('round_icon2');
        }
    });

    $('.round_icon').mouseout(function () {
        var style2 = {
            width: '300px',
            height: '300px'
        }
        busy = true;
        $(this).stop().animate(style2, 200, function() {
            busy = false;
        }).removeClass('round_icon2');
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

As `HerrSerker` points out you are better off with `mouseenter`, but it makes little difference with the other solutions in place. Here it is anyway with `mouseenter` so you can see http://jsfiddle.net/a5Ljuqdn/9/

To try and avoid the problem, you could always place a transparent wrapper behind the circle (same size) to catch the events. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/a5Ljuqdn/11/ This needs styling fixes but you get the idea. I would not recommend it myself as the mouse interaction seems odd (as it does not match the circles).

Comment: but when i am hovering to the border it is acting wired (on your given link)

Comment: @user3396867: It will do that with the chosen way of animating (resizing the mouse over target always does this). I have put up a solution for you that stops the additional events.

Comment: @user3396867: It is still not perfect (touch the bottom edge), but to fix it completely you need to decide what you want the mouse to do if it is on the border and makes the circle small so that the mouse is not on the border any more. *Maybe put a fixed transparent circle behind it so the size for the mouse does not change?*

Comment: i want the same design and same effect, how can i do that. thanks

Comment: @user3396867: I'm afraid you ask for contradictory things. If the mouse must interact with the circle, then it will move outside if the target becomes smaller and then the target will be come larger again. You need to change the interaction to make it do anything differently. What are you willing to change to avoid the bounce? Allow mouse to stay outside circle? Move the cursor (which you cannot do from Javascript)?

Comment: ok. how can i make the circle smaller on hover. with any effect? it is possible? thanks for your help

Comment: And when would you want to make it bigger again?

Comment: when the mouse release

Comment: @user3396867: There is no mouse release unless you have a click.  Are you wanting click to open then release to close?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var main = function () {

    $('.round_icon').mouseover(function () {


        var style1 = {
            width: '200px',
            height: '200px'
        }
        var elm = $(this);
        $(this).stop().animate(style1, 200)
        $('.round_icon').promise().done(function () {
            elm.addClass('round_icon2');

        });

    });

    $('.round_icon').mouseout(function () {


        var style2 = {
            width: '300px',
            height: '300px'
        }
        var elm = $(this);
        $(this).stop().animate(style2, 200).removeClass('round_icon2');
        $('.round_icon').promise().done(function () {
            elm.removeClass('round_icon2');
        });

    });

};


$(document).ready(main);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a5Ljuqdn/6/)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) events will trigger on the subelements as well.
Use [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events instead

http://jsfiddle.net/a5Ljuqdn/7/

```
$('.round_icon').mouseenter(function () {
    var style1 = {
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px'
    }
    $(this).animate(style1, 200).addClass('round_icon2');
});

$('.round_icon').mouseleave(function () {
    var style2 = {
        width: '300px',
        height: '300px'
    }
    $(this).animate(style2, 200).removeClass('round_icon2');
});
```

Comment: when i am hovering on a border it is not working correctly. thanks

Comment: Borders don't seem to catch mouse events. But you could just wrap a  div around your elements, on triggerevents on THAT.